# How to remove extra space in bottom? I have explained in below

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to remove extra space in bottom,Using Language and framework are HTML,CSS,Bootstrap-4. Can someone please help me out  with this extra space problem ? Its my first question in stackoverflow , so please consider my mistakes.

I have specified problem in screenshot .
[Screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acDUi.png)

```css
section#services-section{
  padding: 0;
}
.services-section-column {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.cover {
  background-color: #663399;
  height: 300px;
}
.block {
  transform: translate(0, -245px);
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.inner-section {
  background: #fff;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.inner-section h1{
  color: #010101;
  font-size:2.2rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 45px 0;
}
.inner-section .services-desciption{
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Fenix', sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="services-section">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 services-section-column">
      <div class="cover"></div>
      <div class="block">
          <div class="inner-section">
           <h1>What we do</h1>
           <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="services-desciption">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
           </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="services-desciption">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
           </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="services-desciption">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
           </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

How to remove extra space in bottom,Using Language and framework are How to remove extra space in bottom,Using Language and framework are HTML,CSS,Bootstrap-4. Can someone please help me out  with this extra space problem ? Its my first question in stackoverflow , so please consider my mistakes.

Comment: where is extra space?

Comment: Run this code and scroll .

Comment: @Hasan Please clarify in the question exactly where the problem is; this makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Please checkout screenshot above .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you want remove `scroll-x` and `scroll-y`, try this:*

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  //Other Codes...
}
```

**Note:** Use full page for see result.

```css
section#services-section{
  padding: 0;
}
.services-section-column {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.cover {
  background-color: #663399;
  height: 300px;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  transform: translate(0, -245px);
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner-section {
  background: #fff;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.inner-section h1{
  color: #010101;
  font-size:2.2rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 45px 0;
}

.inner-section .services-desciption{
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Fenix', sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="services-section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 services-section-column">
        <div class="cover"></div>
          <div class="block">
            <div class="inner-section">
              <h1>What we do</h1>
              <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="services-desciption">
       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
     </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="services-desciption">
       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
     </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="services-desciption">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
      </div>
    </div>
     </div>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set translate(0,-245px) on .block, the div has translated up but is still occupying the space, I have a proposed solution,

Add `position:relative` to `.services-section-column`

```
.services-section-column {
  position:relative;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

And set `position:absolute` in `.block`

```
.block {
  transform: translate(0, -245px);
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 40px); // Fix for paddings
}
```

Check the snippet below: (Try Resizing the window to see the difference)

```css
section#services-section{
  padding: 0;
}
.services-section-column {
  position:relative;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.cover {
  background-color: #663399;
  height: 300px;
}
.block {
  transform: translate(0, -245px);
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 40px); // Fix for paddings
}
.inner-section {
  background: #fff;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.inner-section h1{
  color: #010101;
  font-size:2.2rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 45px 0;
}
.inner-section .services-desciption{
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Fenix', sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="services-section">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 services-section-column">
      <div class="cover"></div>
      <div class="block">
          <div class="inner-section">
           <h1>What we do</h1>
           <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="services-desciption">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
           </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="services-desciption">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
           </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="services-desciption">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
           </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</section>
```